# heap size error from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, out-of-memory, heap-size

I have an class journey

```
package com.firstgroup.bbrailapps.pushport.timetable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElements;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="2">
 *           &lt;element ref="{http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/XmlTimetable/v7/rttiCTTSchema.xsd}OR"/>
 *           &lt;element ref="{http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/XmlTimetable/v7/rttiCTTSchema.xsd}IP"/>
 *           &lt;element ref="{http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/XmlTimetable/v7/rttiCTTSchema.xsd}DT"/>
 *           &lt;element ref="{http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/XmlTimetable/v7/rttiCTTSchema.xsd}PP"/>
 *         &lt;/choice>
 *         &lt;element ref="{http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/XmlTimetable/v7/rttiCTTSchema.xsd}AS" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *       &lt;attribute name="rid" use="required" type="{http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/XmlTimetable/v7/rttiCTTSchema.xsd}RIDType" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="uid" type="{http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/XmlTimetable/v7/rttiCTTSchema.xsd}UIDType" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="ssd" use="required" type="{http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/XmlTimetable/v7/rttiCTTSchema.xsd}RTTIDateType" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="trainId" type="{http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/XmlTimetable/v7/rttiCTTSchema.xsd}TrainIdType" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="toc" type="{http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/XmlTimetable/v7/rttiCTTSchema.xsd}TOCType" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="qtrain" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}boolean" default="false" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="status" use="required" type="{http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/XmlTimetable/v7/rttiCTTSchema.xsd}CIFTrainStatusType" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="trainCat" use="required" type="{http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/XmlTimetable/v7/rttiCTTSchema.xsd}CIFTrainCategoryType" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="deleted" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}boolean" default="false" />
 *       &lt;attribute name="can" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}boolean" default="false" />
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "orOrIPOrDT",
    "as"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Journey")
public class Journey {

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "OR", type = OR.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "PP", type = PP.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "IP", type = IP.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "DT", type = DT.class)
    })
    protected List<Object> orOrIPOrDT;
    @XmlElement(name = "AS")
    protected List<AS> as;
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    protected String rid;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String uid;
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    protected String ssd;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String trainId;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected String toc;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected Boolean qtrain;
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    protected String status;
    @XmlAttribute(required = true)
    protected String trainCat;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected Boolean deleted;
    @XmlAttribute
    protected Boolean can;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the orOrIPOrDT property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the orOrIPOrDT property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getOROrIPOrDT().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link OR }
     * {@link PP }
     * {@link IP }
     * {@link DT }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<Object> getOROrIPOrDT() {
        if (orOrIPOrDT == null) {
            orOrIPOrDT = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.orOrIPOrDT;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the as property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the as property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getAS().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link AS }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<AS> getAS() {
        if (as == null) {
            as = new ArrayList<AS>();
        }
        return this.as;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the rid property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getRid() {
        return rid;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the rid property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setRid(String value) {
        this.rid = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the uid property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the uid property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setUid(String value) {
        this.uid = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the ssd property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public String getSsd() {
        return ssd;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the ssd property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link XMLGregorianCalendar }
     *     
     */
    public void setSsd(String value) {
        this.ssd = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the trainId property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getTrainId() {
        return trainId;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the trainId property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setTrainId(String value) {
        this.trainId = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the toc property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getToc() {
        return toc;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the toc property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setToc(String value) {
        this.toc = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the qtrain property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public Boolean isQtrain() {
            return qtrain;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the qtrain property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public void setQtrain(Boolean value) {
        this.qtrain = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the status property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the status property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setStatus(String value) {
        this.status = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the trainCat property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getTrainCat() {
        return trainCat;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the trainCat property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setTrainCat(String value) {
        this.trainCat = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the deleted property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public Boolean isDeleted() {
            return deleted;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the deleted property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public void setDeleted(Boolean value) {
        this.deleted = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the can property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public Boolean isCan() {
            return can;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the can property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Boolean }
     *     
     */
    public void setCan(Boolean value) {
        this.can = value;
    }

}
```

---

when i add around 60,000 object of journey class in arraylist. It gives java.lang.outofmemory error and I have increased max size to 1GB of heapsize. Does there is any other option than ArrayList for large elements.

Comment: Could you post the way you load it ?

Comment: The `ArrayList` is unlikely to be your problem. Though, sizing the `ArrayList` appropriately at instantiation would help.

Comment: I read a xml file then add element to arraylist.
private List<Journey> lstJourney = new ArrayList<Journey>();
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

  // logger.info("END element "+qName);
  if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("Journey")) {
   // printJourney(journey);
   lstJourney.add(journey);
}
}

Comment: Hi Brett, I gave instantiation size to it 50k but same issue.

Comment: Are you allowed to use something other than Sax ? Cause Sax load the entire file in memory before processing it.
If it's possible you could probably try something like that http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/12/difference-between-dom-and-sax-parsers.html  This says that SAX read file according to tag not entire file at same time.

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayList` as such probably isn't the problem; it's just more likely to break since `ArrayList` allocates twice the array size when you add more elements than the current array can contain, i.e. when the internal array of elements is full, it will double the array and copy everything over. So for a short amount of time, it will need `size()*3` times the memory (the actual numbers are slightly different but you get the idea).

You could use other lists, but they need even more memory but in small chunks.

The error above also depends on the size of each `Journey` object. 60K objects isn't that much but if each is 10KB, then that needs 600 MB or 60% of the 1GB you gave the Java VM.

Workarounds:

1. Instead of keeping the whole object in RAM, remember the start and end positions in the file. That just takes a few bytes. When someone requests an object, use `RandomFileAccess` to read just the XML for the single journey and parse it.
2. Instead of keeping all the objects in memory, put the data into a database.